# What does rd stand for in rdstate and rdbuf?

Tags: c++, std

There are two names in C++ standard I/O library: `rdstate` and `rdbuf`. I know "state" and "buf", but what is "rd"?

(PS: I believe I know how to use `rdstate` and `rdbuf`, don't teach me that).

Comment: what does rd usually stand for? ...read...

Comment: @MitchWheat & MarkGarcia oh my god, thank you!

Comment: as everybody knows, "read" should be speled "rd", "halt" should be speled "hlt" and "create" should be speled "creat". so there

Comment: I can understand the confusion here. These are badly named functions. Especially `rdbuf`. Reading the buffer is something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They stand for "read" I think, similar to how most people use "getXXX".

Comment: Some people agree to understand this as the (b)ac(k)ronym for [raw device/data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58024292/2932052).