# What does STL "rdbuf" method name stand for?

Tags: c++, stl

The user who asked the following question accepted "read buffer" pretty fast:
[What does rd stand for in rdstate and rdbuf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080153/what-does-rd-stand-for-in-rdstate-and-rdbuf)

I still wonder what "read buffer" would mean in the context of "std::ostream" (cout). I did not find ANY STL documentation describing this function as doing any "reading". Is that just a misnamed function? (...apparently, but maybe I am missing something)

Comment: This will probably remain a mystery but I always *assumed* it means "read the *address* of the stream buffer". Also `STL` refers to the *containers, iterators and algorithms* only.

Comment: @Galik or _raw device buffer_.

Comment: iostream name choices were failbit.  If Jerry Schwartz shows up to apologize, are you going to do anything different?  Best to leave him in peace.

Comment: I can find nothing in the C++ Standard that refers to this by any name other than simply `rdbuf`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I still wonder what "read buffer" would mean in the context of "std::ostream" (cout).

It's "read" as in "read the value of" or "get the value of" not read as in "read from the stream".

It seems to be a common convention in the old Cfront code, e.g. see the Task library described in the [Cfront 2.0 documentation](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_2.0/doc/LibraryManual.pdf) which has several functions named like that, e.g. on page 2-5:

```
int    rdcount();
int    rdmode();
int    rdmax();
void   setmode(int);
void   setmax(int);
```

So "rd" and "set" seem to be used for names of getters and setters respectively.

That means the overload of `rdbuf(basic_streambuf<C,T>*)` that replaces the streambuf is misnamed, it should be `setbuf`, but that name is already used by the streambuf itself with a different meaning. That `rdbuf` "setter" overload was added later, the original design only had the "getter", as shown in the STRSTREAM(3C++) manual page at the end of the PDF linked to above:

```
class strstream : public strstreambase,  public iostream {
public:
                                 strstream();
                                 strstream(char*, int, int mode);
                 strstreambuf*   rdbuf() ;
                 char*           str();
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Raw Device/Data Buffer (rdbuf)   <---- I prefer @Daniel Jour's comments.

### input_stream is associated with a stream_buffer which is often instantiated by string_buffer or file_buffer.

like:
   explicit basic_istream( std::basic_streambuf* sb);
reference:

### https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/basic_istream

class basic_streambuf is an Abstraction of Raw Device. that means it may socket, file, namedpipe, mailslot, memory, graphycard-mem.
so from high level, how to name the different devices?

I think both RD(raw device) and raw data are ok, but raw device more accurate, even 99.999% times it points to a memory.

Comment: I also found this backronym captivating at first. But then again, `rdbuf` is also available for `std::stringstream` for example, so maybe we'd better learn to accept the confusing alias for the *get* prefix.